# How to open a link in new window in mac

Tags: javascript, html

In mac if I try to open link using `window.open()` function it is opening as new tab instead of new window when the browser screen is maximized. But the same works when browser screen is not maximized.

Comment: window.open works in windows machine to open in new window. But same will not work in mac it will open in new tab

Comment: That is generally not your choice any more these days, it's the user's. My browser is configured to _never_ open new windows, always just full-sized tabs.